# Splitting a large task to Azure functions and collecting the results (implementing a barrier over a service-bus)

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-functions

I have tasks that I need to perform in Azure. each task is broken into several parts that need to run in parallel. The number of parts is not known in advance.

I would like to implement this using Azure functions and service bus. I was thinking about the following architecture:
[image: System flow]

I receive the task in a service bus. Func 1 determines how many sub-parts should be created, Func 2 does the work, and func 3 collects the results and passes them using a service bus.

I could not find an efficient mechanism for collecting the (variable) number of sub-results and knowing when everything has completed; If all sub-parts are ready passing the combined results to the output service bus.

Is there such a mechanism in Azure for collecting results from parallel sub-parts and only after everything is ready sending the data to the next stage? (this is like the [barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)) synchronization mechanism).

Comment: Could Azure Batch be a better fit? And are you dealing with a lot of data? If yes, this feels like you could use MapReduce. Otherwise I am afraid you'd need to store your custom barrier like data somewhere - lots of choices for that in Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach:

Function 1 gets the work from it's message queue. It creates a jobId (GUID) that will be used to correlate all of the pieces. It breaks up the work into sub-parts and records the jobId and sub-parts in a database.

Each sub-part becomes a message that is added into the message queue that Func 2 is listening on.

Once Func 2 receives and processes the message, it places a message in the queue for Func 3.

Func 3 records in the db that this sub-part of the job has completed and check to see if now all of the sub-parts are complete. If they are not, do nothing else, if it is, it now knows that everything has completed and can proceed.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check Logic Apps to govern the whole process. You can [trigger from Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus), [invoke individual functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions) through a loop etc. and incorporate results back to the document.

Comment: Yes Logic Apps has parallel and join concepts where the engine could wait for all to complete an aggregate results. Happy to help show you with an example -- logicappsemail@microsoft.com